# Frozen PVC pipes in Texas

Tags: pvc

I have frozen water pipes and I poured boiling water down the bathtub drain and now have a small amount of hot water coming out cold water tap.

What could cause this?

Comment: @jsotola I'd guess she accidentally hit `ctrl-B` while typing. The SE editor puts in the appropriate coding to make for **bold** text. She noticed and deleted some of it, but not all of it.

Comment: Leave the tap running at least a small amount even cold water will help to melt the ice blockage open cabinet doors at sinks and bathtub areas to help warm the walls. Hopefully nothing broke. But it was probably just a fluke that the water started running after dumping down the drain.